# Problems getting default wallpapers from previous versions

Tags: desktop-background, design

I was trying to figure out how to get the wallpapers from the previous versions of Ubuntu and luckily I found out how by a good fellow. You just install them from the official repositories. The reason for wanting to do this was to get Ubuntu 15.10 (Wily WereWolf's) Default Wallpaper. Installing the wallpapers from any of the previous versions doesn't not install the default wallpapers. This is really odd, hope someone can help figure out this really stupid problem :D

Answer (score 1):

Welp figured it out, I just downloaded the 15.10 iso and ran it in virtualbox, went to /usr/share/backgrounds and grabbed the wallpaper. Simple enough :D